# Collapsing pointers inside a templated class?

Tags: c++, vector

Here is my code:

```
template<typename B>
class cvector{

public:

    cvector(){    
    allocatedSize =0;
    actualSize = 0;
    buffer = 0;
    }


    cvector(int k):allocatedSize(k){

    }


    cvector(int k, const B& initial ):allocatedSize(k), actualSize(k){

    buffer = new B[allocatedSize];

        for(int i = 0;i<allocatedSize;i++){
            buffer[i] = initial;
        }   
    }

    ~cvector(){
        delete [] buffer;                   
    }


private:
    int allocatedSize;
    int actualSize;
    B* buffer;

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

cvector<int> pee(2,int(5));
cvector<int*> kay(2,new int(10));
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to emulate `std::vector`. My code isn't optimized and clean yet as this is just a draft but as of now, i get no problems and here are my test cases when initializing:

```
cvector<int> p(2,int(5));                   //no error
cvector<int*> k(2,new int(10));             //no error
cvector<int> j(2,new int(5));               // error because it's int
cvector<int*> l(2,int(2));                  //error because it's a pointer
```

I am curious how are these `B` expressions evaluated if i will put `int` or `int*` ?

```
B* buffer;                           // (int*)* so int *? (just like reference collapsing?
buffer = new B[allocatedSize];       // new int* if int* ?!
```

So if i wil use `int*` then `B* buffer;` will be `int*` ?
what about  `buffer = new B[allocatedSize];` and `const B& initial` from my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Pointer collapsing" doesn´t exist.
No stars will be added or removed or anything else.

```
B* buffer;
buffer = new B[allocatedSize];
```

with B being `int` results in

```
int* buffer;
buffer = new int[allocatedSize];
```

ie. an array of `int`, and you can do whatever you want with the `int`´s.

With B being `int*`, it will be

```
int** buffer;
buffer = new int*[allocatedSize];
```

ie. an array of int pointers, all pointers pointing nowhere (initially),
and you can do whatever you want with your pointers.

Comment: Ahhh i see, i thought they apply the same principle as reference collapsing.

Comment: @CarloBrew, reference collapsing exists because you can't create reference to reference. Such construction just doesn't exist in C++. But you can create pointer to pointer to pointer to pointer ... So it makes no sense to have pointer collapsing.

Comment: @ixSci so from this line of code `buffer = new int*[allocatedSize];  `, which is dynamically constructed by new?

Comment: @CarloBrew, pointers to int. So after this line you need a cycle to allocate memory for every pointer in the  "array" with `allocatedSize` size

Comment: @ixSci So how do i clean it up? let's say i made a class like this `carl **  c = new carl*[10];` and i allocated each othem through `carl[0] = new carl()`, i tried with `delete [] c` and the destructors weren't called.

Comment: @CarloBrew, you have to go other way around: first go through all the objects and delete them: `delete c[0];` ... then delete the "root" pointer `delete [] c;`

Answer (score 1):

> how are these B expressions evaluated if i will put int or int* ?

For `int`, the `B` will be `int*` and for `int*`, the `B` will be `int**`.

> So if i wil use int* then B* buffer; will be int* ? what about  buffer
>   = new B[allocatedSize]; and `const B& initial` from my code?

No. `B*` will be `int**` as mentioned above. For `int*` the expression would look like:

```
(int**)buffer = new int*[allocatedSize];
```

The `const B& initial` would be evaluated as `const int*&`.

With my advice, for the production code you may think above having `std::vector` as an object and `cvector` as a wrapper around it. Or inherit `cvector` from `std::vector` in a kind of ["has a"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) relationship.

Comment: So what does `const int*&` means ? I'm somehow confused with this

Comment: @CarloBrew, you are copying the argument passed to the constructor by a `const` reference. It is "const" because, it's not supposed to change inside the constructor. It is reference because, you may not want to copy the whole structure unnecessarily. For example, imaging that you are using `cvector` on some class with 100s of bytes. If you pass it as value then the whole class object would be copied. e.g. `class A { int a[100]; }; A temp; cvector<A> obj(2, temp);`

Comment: I mean the `*&` sign, so it's like a pointer and reference at the same time? or they are just treated like a normal reference?

Comment: @CarloBrew, it is reference of a pointer. It is similar to reference of an object only. Just that it is a pointer. Also suppose if you remove `const` from the constructor 2nd argument then it will not compile for 2nd test case because a reference to temporary is not allowed, be it object or pointer.

Comment: @CarloBrew, `*&` meanse reference to pointer. Essentially it means that if you change the pointer variable inside the function then you will see the changed pointer outside the function.